# Insert a figure into a subplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, subplot

I am having problem in creating nested subplot in Matlab. I am trying to create two figures. The first figure, fig1 contains 4x4=16 subplots. Each of these subplots are consist of another figure fig2, which is itself made up of a number of subplots of dimension Nx1, where N varies depending on different data.

After reading various threads, I tried the following way. First I generate the fig2, then save it temporarily, and then load it and try to save it in subplot of figure1. But I am having two problems. First I think this approach is slow, and even then, I am encountering error message. The code in short is as follows:

```
for i=1:16  h(i)=subplot(4,4,i);end   %To  get the positions of the subplots
pos=get(h,'Position');
delete(h);


hf2=figure(2);

for i=1:16
  hf1=figure(1);
  for j=1:N
  % Plot the figure for hf1
  end

 saveas(hf1,'temp.fig')

 figure(2);
 hf2(i)=subplot(4,4,i);

 hg1=hgload('temp.fig');
 ax1=gca;

 fig=get(ax1,'children');   % To copy the figure to subplot
 copyobj(fig,hf(i));

 hax=get(hg1,'Child');   % This part to resize the figure to the size of subplot
 set(hax,'Parent',hf2);
 set(hax,'Position',pos{i});  

end
```

But the above code throws up the following error

```
Error using set
Invalid property found.
Object Name: uitoolbar
Property Name: 'Position'.
```

I have taken some parts of above code from stackoverflow itself, and might be using a few part inappropriately, but not sure where. Also, is there a better method for the above task, or the above way is the simplest and most flexible? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you can write out your sub-images as individual images of publication quality, I suppose you could make a `montage` of them, but either this is going to become one very big image or your subplots will become unreadable.  Is there a good reason for having everything in one figure?

Comment: Yes creating a montage also is an option. I was actually looking for a command line utility which can arrange eps files in 4x4 matrix. But couldn't find it in unix. Merging eps after converting to pdf mergred them sequentially in single row..

Comment: You might want to look into ImageMagick (not sure if it handles .eps directly with the `montage` command or not).

Comment: Just checked it, looks like it will be perfect :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: bt the image print quality is actually not very good, at least in the default options. Will look for more options.